# Pandas Group to Divide by Max

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to normalize a user count by dividing by the max users in each group. I'm able to get the results to calculate (commented out the print that works), but I'm having trouble getting the results to save back to the original table. The code below doesn't throw an error, but it also doesn't add any data to weeklyPerson:

```
weeklyPersonGroups=weeklyPerson.groupby('Person')
PersonMax=weeklyPersonGroups['users'].max()
for name, group in weeklyPersonGroups:
    #print(weeklyPerson[weeklyPerson['Person']==name]['users']/PersonMax[name])
    weeklyPerson[weeklyPerson['Person']==name]['usersNorm']=weeklyPerson[weeklyPerson['Person']==name]['users']/PersonMax[name]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `groupby` and [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html)

```
weeklyPerson.groupby('Person').users.transform(lambda x: x / x.max())
```

Per [@Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/644898)'s [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39282355/pandas-group-to-divide-by-max#comment65899739_39282362)

```
weeklyPerson.users / weeklyPerson.groupby('Person').users.transform(np.max)
```

This avoids using `lambda` when it isn't necessary.

Comment: this is very inefficient; don't use a lamba inside transform if not necessary (it's not here)

Comment: @Jeff working on this comment as well as your other one.

Comment: Thanks for both of your comments! Either is far more elegant than what I was trying to do. What is it about the lambda function that makes it less efficient? I found that answer to look more intuitive.